# how to convert object of one type(Interface) to another(Interface)?

Tags: java, interface

I have an an interface Interface1 which has been implemented by class A and has some private variables value set and m sending the object of class A to next class which accepts input as Interface2. so how can i covert this object refering to Interface1 to Interface2?

```
interface Interface1{}
interface Interface2{}

class A implements Interface1 {
    private int id;

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class B {
    Interface1 call(Interface1 i)
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.call2(i); //this should be of type Interface2 so how to do this
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Interface1 i = new A();
        i.setId(5);
        B b = new B();
        b.call(i);
    }
}

class c {
    Interface2 call2(Interface2 i)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can cast from interface1 to interface2, unless one inherits from the other. The cast syntax is usually (interface2) xyz;

Comment: Are the two interfaces related in any way? The intent of you code is not very clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `Interface1` and `Interface2` are two totally irrelevant interfaces, how suppose an `A` instance being able to use as `Interface2`?  `A` may even not have `Interface2` methods defined.

There are several way you can do to make this a bit more proper design.

First, if you want to keep Interface1 and 2 as two irrelevant interfaces, you should have `A` implements both of them:

```
class A implements Interface1, Interface2 {
```

and at least you can do some casting for that in `B#call()`:

```
if (i instanceof Interface2) {
    Interface2 i2 = (Interface2) i;
    ....
    c.call2(i2);
}
```

If in your design it is appropriate to have Interface1 and 2 have inheritance relationship, story may be a bit easier:

```
interface Interface1 extends Interface2 {
```

Then Interface1 can be used as Interface2 directly.

Another possibility is, if you know that, by whatever you provide by Interface1, it can be somehow used as Interface2 (e.g. somehow like Java's Runnable and Callable), you may write an Interface2 adapter for Interface1:

```
class Interface1I2Adapter implements Interface2 {
    Interface1 i1;
    public Interface1I2Adapter (Interface1 i1) {
         this.i1 = i1;
    }
    // impl of Interface2 methods by delegating to i1
}
```

and then you can use by

```
c.call2(new Interface1I2Adapter(i));
```

something like that.

Without further information on your design, it is impossible to suggest what are the correct ways for you.  Here are some suggestions that works in a lot of cases.

Comment: While trying your comment the second part (this.i1 = i1), I have lost data present in Interface1. so is there some other way

Comment: @user3701528 what do you mean by that? Can you give an actual example to demonstrate why you need to do all these things? I believe that's simply some design problem which you can deal with using other ways.  Because what you are asking for is simply irrational imho

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
 class D implements Interface2{}
```

---

```
C c = new C();
D d = new D();
d.set...(i.get...());
c.call2(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do ditto conversion from one interface to another because they are independent abstractions. Alternatively, You can achieve this by making Interface1 as subclass of Interface2.  You should extend Interface2 as follows and use it:

```
  interface Interface1 extends Interface2{  
      void setId(int id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Interface1 should extend Interface2 in order to pass Interface1 reference to Interface2.

Correct code-

```
interface Interface1 extends Interface2 { //Imp



}

interface Interface2  {
public void setId(int id);
}

class A implements Interface1 {
private int id;

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}

public class B {
Interface1 call(Interface1 i) {
    C c = new C();
    c.call2(i); // this should be of type Interface2 so how to do this
    return i;
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    Interface1 i = new A();
    i.setId(5);
    B b = new B();
    b.call(i);
}
 }

class C {
Interface2 call2(Interface2 i) {
    return i;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is usually solved through [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

To compose an existing interface you would write a class that implements Interface2 and delegates to an internal instance of Interface1.

This idea is expressed further with the Go4 [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).